# Access Pytest marks from parametrize in the test

Tags: python, pytest, pytest-markers

I have a very large of set tests that use `@pytest.mark.parametrize` with a fairly large set of custom marks. I can't figure out a way to access those marks from within the test. The [documentation](https://docs.pytest.org/en/7.1.x/example/markers.html#reading-markers-which-were-set-from-multiple-places) explains how to do this from a `conftest.py` file, but not from the test function.

I don't really need to operate on the marks, all I need is to register them.

`pytest.ini`:

```
[pytest]
markers =
    MarkFoo
    MarkBar
```

`test.py`:

```py
import pytest

from typing import Any
from dataclasses import dataclass

@dataclass(frozen=True)
class FooTest:
    name: str                           # Unique test name
    param: int                          # A parameter
    marks: Any = ()                     # Marks for this test


test_list = [
    FooTest(name='Foo', param=1, marks=(pytest.mark.MarkFoo)),
    FooTest(name='Bar', param=2, marks=(pytest.mark.MarkBar)),
]

@pytest.mark.parametrize( "name, param, ",
    [ pytest.param(t.name, t.param, marks=t.marks) for t in test_list ]
)

def test_run_foo_bar(name, param, record_property):
    # How to read the marks here?
    # record_property("marks:", ???)
    print(name, param)
```

How can I access the marks from the test? Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

Turns out it's super simple if you use a fixture:

```py
@pytest.fixture()
def test_marks(request):
    marks = ["MarkFoo", "MarkBar"]
    return [m for m in request.node.own_markers if m.name in marks]

def test_run_foo_bar(name, param, record_property, test_marks):
    record_property("Test Marks:", test_marks)
    print(name, param, test_marks)
```